# How to encapsulate Picker within UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, datepicker

Anybody can give more detail about the answer to the question "How do I make a modal date picker that only covers half the screen?" which is answered by user eladleb.

```
@interface pickerCell : UITableViewCell
{
    UITextField *txtTextField;
    UIPickerView* dtpPicker;
}
```

especially step 2, 3, 4, anybody can elaborate in detail(i.e. which method...)? sample codes are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should add a comment to the answer of eladleb asking for guidance.

Comment: It seems that I am not allowed to add comments to original answer any more.

Comment: @eladleb open source ActionSheetPicker seems a good solution, right?

Answer (score 0):

iOS has a UIActionSheet that is designed for uses just like that.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

There is also an open source framework that will take a lot of the work out of putting the picker in an actionsheet.  This way, when a user taps a cell, show the action sheet.

https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker